# how to update item list like shopping cart?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have purchase order form where I am storing product details in session i.e product name, quantity, rate etc. It is working fine. But when I edit that purchase order I get already stored session data correctly but when user enter another product , it overrides first records. Means only newly added record is displayed. Old record disappear. Following is my code for purchase order form add to cart button..

```
function index(){       

    $data= array('product_id'=>$this->input->post('product_id'),
        'quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity'),
        'unit'=>$this->input->post('unit'),
        'unit_rate'=>$this->input->post('unit_rate'));


    //Get the cart

    $cart = $this->session->userdata('data');
    //Add data to this temporary variable
    $cart[] = $data;
    //Set back the data
    $this->session->set_userdata('data', $cart);
    $post_array['cart']=$this->session->userdata('data')
    ?>

    <tr>
        <th>Product  Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Unit Rate</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i=0;
    foreach($post_array['cart'] as $item){

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM phppos_items WHERE 
 item_id='".$item['product_id']."'");
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $product_name=$row->name;

        }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$product_name."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['quantity']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['unit']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item['unit_rate']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='javascript:void(0)' rownum='".$i."' 
    class='remove_from_cart'><img src='images/close.png'/></a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    ?>

    <?php
 }
```

I am getting old session data array in this.

```
 $this->session->userdata('sess_products');
```

**I want to know how do I update that session array with new data?**
**I am calling this same while editing.**

Answer (score 1):

hey it is the same way you are adding session data for update.

> $this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');

[Click this Link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the CODEIGNITER INBUILT SHOPPING LIB.

[Check Link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html)

Answer (score 0):

use separators to connect multiple things

```
$item=$this->session->userdata('item');
$item=$update."+"."New item";
$price=$this->session->userdata('price');
$price=$price."+"."New price"; //add as much as u want(but you can store only 4kb in CI session. so restrict add multiple things in cart)
$this->session->set_userdata('item',$item);
$this->session->set_userdata('price',$price);
```

this might help you

Comment: Above code is for adding product details. what changes should I make for editing??

Comment: I am getting already stored data correctly and then I am storing it in session and displaying while editing but I want to append new data array to that existing array

Comment: when you update your cart list just use separators to connect multiple things in one string because Codeignitor session does not allow to pass multiple arrays. so go with separator